# xdebug.profiler_enable causes cachegrind files that take up too much memory

Tags: macos, memory, drupal, xdebug, cachegrind

Good morning,

My mac ran out of working memory today, which was odd. I checked out where the space was being used, and it was in my log/xdebug file, nearly 20 GB of cachegrind.out files! I've only had  xdebug.profiler_enable on for about 3-4 weeks, and I'm using PHPStorm for some debugging, though not much.

How can I tell xdebug to delete more than x entries or only save x megabytes of data?

Or is there something *terribly wrong*?

For reference, my stack is OSX native Apache with mod_fastcgi for PHP, and PHP and MariaDB installed using homebrew. Usually developing on Drupal, and, yes, Drupal 6 on PHP 5.4 throws a bunch of errors because it has maintained support for PHP 4. Blech. Still 20 gigs? Geez. That's like a gig a day.

Thanks in advance!